# ¿Cómo mostrar los datos de una lista en jasperreport?

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports

Estoy generando un reporte en jasper reports, el documento pide los datos Cantidad, UnidadMedida, Descripcion, Precio e Importe.
Entre todos los datos, los únicos que no se mandan son los de la lista, ni siquiera se reciben, trata de agregar el JRBeanCollectionArrayDataSource pero me marca error, porque me dice que no se puede convertir de JRBeanCollectionDataSource a JRBeanCollectionArrayDataSource.

Este es mi reporte y esto es lo que pide

[image: Así se ve mi reporte]

Ahora este es mi procedimiento, el ds comentado es el parámetro de la tabla

```
public List<ArticulosPdf> DaArticulosPdf(String folio){
        List<ArticulosPdf> nuevalista = generapdf.lista(folio);
        return nuevalista;
    }
    
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> GeneraElPdf (String Folio, String cliente) throws FileNotFoundException, JRException{
        String Nombre           = generapdf.DaNombre(cliente);
        String Calle            = generapdf.DaCalle(cliente);
        String Telefono         = generapdf.DaTelefono(cliente);
        String RFC              = generapdf.DaRFC(cliente);
        Date   Fecha            = generapdf.DaFecha(Folio);
        Date   FechaVencimiento = generapdf.DaFechaVencimiento(Folio);
        String Condiciones      = generapdf.DaCondiciones(Folio);
        double Subtotal         = generapdf.DaSubtotal(Folio);
        double Iva              = generapdf.DaIva(Folio);
        double Descuento        = generapdf.DaDescuento(Folio);
        double Total            = generapdf.DaTotal(Folio);
        
        
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(this.DaArticulosPdf(Folio));
        JasperReport compileReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(new FileInputStream("src/main/java/Reporte/DocPdf.jrxml"));
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        map.put("Folio", Folio);
        map.put("Clave", cliente);
        map.put("Nombre", Nombre);
        map.put("Calle", Calle);
        map.put("Telefono",Telefono);
        map.put("RFC", RFC);
        map.put("Fecha", Fecha);
        map.put("FechaVencimiento", FechaVencimiento);
        map.put("Condiciones", Condiciones);
        map.put("Subtotal", Subtotal);
        map.put("Iva", Iva);
        map.put("Descuento", Descuento);
        map.put("Total", Total);
        
        JasperPrint report = JasperFillManager.fillReport(compileReport,map,beanCollectionDataSource);
        byte[] data  = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(report);
        HttpHeaders header = new  HttpHeaders();
        header.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "Inline;filename=FOCB720120LB7_FAC-Pedido-V.pdf");
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(header).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF).body(data);
    }
```

En mi clase GeneraPdf, es de donde obtengo mis datos para el llenado de la tabla

```
public List<ArticulosPdf> lista(String folio){
        String consulta = "select Cantidad, UnidadMedida, Descripcion, Precio, Importe from VPedidoD where Folio='"+folio+"'";
        List<ArticulosPdf> listaArticulos = this.getJdbcTemplate().query(consulta, mapper);
        return listaArticulos;
    }
```

Esta es mi clase Mapper

public class GeneraPDFMapper  implements RowMapper{

@Override
public ArticulosPdf mapRow(ResultSet rs, int row) throws SQLException{

```
    double Cantidad     = rs.getDouble("Cantidad");
    String UnidadMedida = rs.getString("UnidadMedida");
    String Descripcion  = rs.getString("Descripcion");
    double Precio       = rs.getDouble("Precio");
    double Importe      = rs.getDouble("Importe");
    
    return new ArticulosPdf(Cantidad,
                            UnidadMedida,
                            Descripcion,
                            Precio,
                            Importe);
}
}
```

Clase ArticulosPdf

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class ArticulosPdf {

   private double Cantidad;
    private String UnidadMedida;
    private String Descripcion;
    private double Precio;
    private double Importe;//VPedidoD
    
                           
}
```

Clase InsersionPdf

```
@Data
public class InsersionPdf {
   private String Folio;
    private String Clave;
    private String Nombre;
    private String Calle;
    private String Telefono;
    private String RFC;//CLIENTE
    private Date   Fecha;
    private Date   FechaVencimiento;
    private String Condiciones;//PEDIDOE
    
    //private String ImporteLetra;
    
    private double Subtotal;
    private double Iva;
    private double Descuento;
    private double Total;//PEDIDOE
    
}
```

Y por último mi controller

```
@GetMapping("Pdf")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> generaPdf(@RequestHeader (name="PdfFolio", required =true)String Folio,
                                            @RequestHeader (name="PdfCliente", required =true)String Cliente) throws Exception, JRException {
        return this.GeneraElPdf(Folio, Cliente);
}
```

Este es el error que me sale

```
nested exception is net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean: Cantidad.] with root cause
```

Comment: Cantidad lo tienes como double en java, en jasper lo recibes como tipo double?, puedes revisar eso para descartar por favor

Comment: Si, lo tengo como java.lang.Double